# Using a Wordpress plugin feature elsewhere within theme files

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I'm using the ultimate member online plugin, which shows members' online status.

When enabled to show on a user's UM profile page, it looks like this, for example: [image]

When creating posts, it is common for data pertaining to the author to display somewhere within the post. For example:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/JRjfHhX.png]

What I'd like to accomplish is to have online status (shown in first image, above) also be displayed within this author data, shown within a post.

I've poked around in theme/plugin files, and I'm CLOSE!

1. I found where I need to edit, within the theme files (wp-content/themes/plum/inc/template-tags.php file)
2. I've narrowed the plugin files and content within them down, to what i believe would be the appropriate code to insert into theme files. Screenshots and copied [relevant] text can be found here: [image]
3. Ive been playing around, reading the web, creating a post on the official wp forums (as well as searching within them), and this is the best I've got so far: [image]

On the surface, it looks like the problem is solved. However, that user ("testAuthor1"), is offline (and the greenlight there in that very last imgur link displays the user as online).

Comment: In the hopes of helping other people in the future, who face a similar problem, it's recommended to include as much data in the post (especially the code), rather than include them via images on an external site. Since the external site may remove them after some time, which would render your question useless for any future reader.

Comment: I strongly suggest replacing those images with a text.